# How to add option "params" in dropzone.js Angular4

Tags: angular, dropzone.js

I'm making an application in angular 4. I'm using dropzone.js to transfer files to back. To use Dropzone.js in angular 4, I'm using [ngx-dropzone-wrapper](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-dropzone-wrapper).

I want to pass a new parameters when a file is sent (with the 'params' options). The parameters is a function that return a string, and the result change on a user click. It's actually a Singleton and the first time it's created is in the ngOnInit() function in the app.component.ts file.

My app.module.ts look like this (where the dropzone.js module is added to the project):

```
import { DropzoneModule, DropzoneConfigInterface } from 'ngx-dropzone-wrapper';
const DROPZONE_CONFIG: DropzoneConfigInterface = {
    url: 'http://localhost:81/api/createFiles',
    maxFilesize: 50,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    params: { 'whereToCreate': **the function goes here** }
};

@NgModule({
...
imports: [
    ...
    DropzoneModule.forRoot(DROPZONE_CONFIG)
```

My HTML using the ngx-dropzone-wrapper (it's exactly like the example in the [github of ngx-dropzone-wrapper](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-dropzone-wrapper)):

```
<dropzone [config]="config" [message]="'Click or drag images here to upload'" (error)="onUploadError($event)" (success)="onUploadSuccess($event)"></dropzone>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know, but Dropzone.js send all the inputs in the form.

So, i transform the div into a form and add a hidden input:

```
<form [dropzone]="config" (error)="onUploadError($event)" (success)="onUploadSuccess($event)">
    <input type="hidden" name="whereToCreate" value="{{ this.currentFolder.get() }}">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: 
When the file is sent it will trigger and many event among them **sending** event in this event you receive as parameters **File , xhr, formData** in the formData you can **.append(key, value)**. Then it will send along with each file the new params.
Your html:

```
        <div class="text-center well">
          <dropzone [config]="dropzoneConfigI"
                [message]="'Click or drag images here to upload'"
                (error)="onError($event)"
                (sending)="onSending($event)"
                (sendingmultiple)="onSendingmultiple($event)"
                (success)="onSuccess($event)"
                (addedfile)="onAddedFile($event)"
           >
           </dropzone>
    </div>
```

your controller:

```
  onSending(data): void {
    // data [ File , xhr, formData]
    const file = data[0];
    const formData = data[2];
    formData.append('order', someIteratorValue);
  }
```

Hope it helps.